# I have a problem when copying and pasting the text from PDF file from my computer in Chrome and Brave Browser

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, copy-paste, brave-browser

I'm facing a problem with copying the text from PDF to anywhere else in Google Chrome, Brave and Microsoft Edge. (Other browsers are not on my computer). This is what I mean. I have a PDF file on my computer that is opened via Brave Browser.

It's the selected text. [image: Selected text]

These are the options of the selected text. There is no word "copy" in Polish "kopiuj" as well as there is no option of paste ("wklej"). [image: Options of the selected text]

Then I tried to use CTRL + C, CTRL + V. This is what I can see.
[image: The third picture.]
It's the link I've copied before. So that means I can copy anything from the Internet when using Google Chrome or Brave Browser, except for text from PDF files.
It all worked very well until Sunday. I don't have an idea what happened. I've searched the Internet to find a solution.
I found the post about the same problem, but it's not the solution on my computer.
https://www.technipages.com/fix-copy-and-paste-not-working-in-chrome
https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0rWjpnswXLec/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Fchrome%2FrWjpnswXLec
Those links don't help me at all. I've done what they tell you. I still cannot copy and paste the text.

Okay, there is another thing. I've scanned my whole computer and there is no virus at all.
Do you have any idea what can I do? Is there any other solution than the links I gave you?

Comment: It's a file from my computer, not a website. The CTRL + U doesn't show anything. When I press it, nothing happens.

Comment: This happens to some PDF files. As I can see now, some of them are working properly. This one you can see isn't. And when I try to copy, then nothing happens. There is no message about the limited restrictions. It just doesn't respond at all. As you can see on the picture. I tried to copy the text from the PDF file, and what I could paste was the web link I had copied just a minute before.